# Scanner not closed error

Tags: java

Hi i am very new to programming and today is in fact my third day into java world. whenever I write a java program with scanner I get warning "scanner is never closed". Please point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("what is your lucky number?");
        int my = scanner.nextInt();

        switch(my) {
        case 7 :
            System.out.println("your choice is correct");
            break;
        case 10 :
            System.out.println("your choice is correct");
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("bad choice");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the *compiler* emit the warning, or do you get it at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `scanner.close()` to the end of the code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a warning because your tool (compiler or IDE?) is smart enough to see that there is an object that implements [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), in your case [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), that you haven't invoked the [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close()) method on. Classes that implement `Closeable` do so because usually `close()` frees up important System resources that otherwise would be leaked. For example sockets or file handles need to be closed after use. There is a pattern for closing anything that implemresources that need to be closed:

In any version of java

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // use the scanner
} finally {
    if (scanner != null) {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

The `finally` block is guaranteed to execute, even if there is an exception thrown in the try block. This ensures that you don't leak a resource.

In Java 7+

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // use the scanner
}
```

Comment: try-with-resources was introduced in Java 7, not 8.

Comment: Although it's relatively common, that particular variation on the "java < 8" approach always irks me.  Since the `new` operator never yields `null`, it is better to instantiate the object immediately prior to the try block, and then not have to worry about a `null` test in the associated `finally` block.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If your intention is not to add a catch block, I would agree. If the constructor throws an exception that you want to catch, it is often convenient to use the pattern I presented.